# Parent-child relationship broken in figures generated by fvtool?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

To reproduce the problem that I am facing, I will use a slightly modified version of one of the examples in the documentation of `fvtool`:

```
b1 = firpm(20,[0 0.4 0.5 1],[1 1 0 0]); 
fvtool(b1, 1, 'Analysis', 'freq');
```

The code above should generate the following figure:

[image: Figure generated by fvtool]

I am trying to manipulate independently the properties of the two lines that you can see in that figure (the phase and amplitude lines). I can easily modify the properties of the magnitude line:

```
h = findobj(gcf, 'Tag', 'magnitude_line');
set(h, 'Color', 'Red');
```

However, I can't do the same for the phase line. Any of the following commands just returns the empty array:

```
h = findobj(gcf, 'Tag', 'phasez_line')
h = findobj('Tag', 'phasez_line')
h = findobj(0, 'Tag', 'phasez_line')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer to my problem, which was actually rather obvious. It seems that `fvtool` sets the `HandleVisibility` property of the `fvtool_axes_2` axes (which is the parent of the phase line) to `callback` and, as a result, such object is not found when using `findobj`. Using `findall` the problem is solved, i.e.:

```
h = findall(0, 'Tag', 'phasez_line');
```

Similarly you can use `allchild` to find such hidden handles, i.e.:

```
parentAxes = findall(0, 'Tag', 'fvtool_axes_2');
% This returns empty
intersect(parentAxes, get(get(parentAxes, 'Parent'), 'Children'))
% But this returns a handle to the fvtool_axes_2 axes
intersect(parentAxes, allchild(get(parentAxes, 'Parent')))
```